# Sequelize - How to insert csv data into multiple tables in mysql using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv, sequelize.js, fast-csv

What I'm using

```
node.js, express, sequelize 6.3.3, fast-csv 4.3.1 and mysql database.
```

What I have

I have a CSV file with following headers and data.

```
no, name, email, township, father_name, father_phone, mother_name, mother_phone, parent_township
```

In this CSV, I have two types of data: `students` and `parents`.

In my `MySQL` database, I have three tables:

```
students, parents and townships
```

Students table:

```
id, name, email, township_id
```

Parents table:

```
id, student_id, father_name, father_phone, mother_name, mother_phone, parent_township_id
```

Townships table:

```
id, name
```

What I've done

I read the CSV with `fast-csv` npm package with the following code.

```js
let csvData = [];

fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
    .pipe(
      csv.parse({
        ignoreEmpty: true,
        trim: true,
        skipLines: 6,
      })
    )
    .on("error", (error) => console.error(error))
    .on("data", (row) => {
      csvData.push(getHeaders(_.compact(row), csvStudentDataEntryFields));
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);

      const data = csvData.map((data) => {
        const student = _.pick(data, studentFields);
        const parent = _.pick(data, parentFields);
        return [student, parent];
      });

      return res.status(201).send({
        status: "success",
        data,
      });
    });
```

What I got

With the above code, I got `data` with following values.

```
[
    [ // row 1 from CSV
        {
            "name": "John",
            "email": "john@gmail.com",
            "township": "NYC",
        },
        {
            "fatherName": "Smith",
            "fatherPhone": "9111111111",
            "motherName": "Mary",
            "motherPhone": "9111111111",
            "parentTownship": "NYC"
         }
    ],
    [ // row 2 from CSV
        {
            "name": "Cutter",
            "email": "cutter@gmail.com",
            "township": "NYC",
        },
        {
            "fatherName": "Laseli",
            "fatherPhone": "9111111111",
            "motherName": "Mary",
            "motherPhone": "9111111111",
            "parentTownship": "NYC"
        }
    ]
]
```

What I want

I want to store those `row 1` and `row 2` from `data` into respective tables in the database.

The problems

I think I need to replace those `township` text data **with real id** because I have foreign keys stated as above.

How can I achieve it? I want to do it in database level. I don't want to look up the `id` of that township name in separate js module.

**Updated**

Student Model

```
class Student extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Student.belongsTo(models.Township, {
        foreignKey: "townshipId",
        as: "township",
        targetKey: "townshipId",
      });

     Student.hasOne(models.Parent, {
        foreignKey: "studentId",
        as: "parent",
        sourceKey: "studentId",
      });
    }
  }
```

Parent Model

```
class Parent extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Parent.belongsTo(models.Student, {
        foreignKey: "studentId",
        as: "student",
        targetKey: "studentId",
      });

      Parent.belongsTo(models.Township, {
        foreignKey: "parentTownshipId",
        as: "township",
        targetKey: "townshipId",
      });
    }
  }
```

Township Model

```
class Township extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Township.hasMany(models.Student, {
        foreignKey: "townshipId",
        as: "township",
        sourceKey: "townshipId",
      });

      Township.hasMany(models.Parent, {
        foreignKey: "townshipId",
        as: "parentTownship",
        sourceKey: "townshipId",
      });
    }
  }
```

**Updated:**

in my controller,

```
let std = await models.Student.create(
    {
        nameEn: "John",
        email: "john@gmail.com",
        townshipId: 1,
        parent: [{ ...d[1], parentTownshipId: 1 }],
    },
    { include: ["parent"] }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can insert all relationship together.

This is from sequelize document

```
const amidala = await User.create({
  username: 'p4dm3',
  points: 1000,
  profiles: [{
    name: 'Queen',
    User_Profile: {
      selfGranted: true
    }
  }]
}, {
  include: Profile
});

const result = await User.findOne({
  where: { username: 'p4dm3' },
  include: Profile
});

console.log(result);
```

set source key

```
 const Foo = sequelize.define('foo', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, unique: true }
}, { timestamps: false });
const Bar = sequelize.define('bar', {
  title: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, unique: true }
}, { timestamps: false });
const Baz = sequelize.define('baz', { summary: DataTypes.TEXT }, { timestamps: false });
Foo.hasOne(Bar, { sourceKey: 'name', foreignKey: 'fooName' });
Bar.hasMany(Baz, { sourceKey: 'title', foreignKey: 'barTitle' });
// [...]
await Bar.setFoo("Foo's Name Here");
await Baz.addBar("Bar's Title Here");
```

ref  https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html#using-one-to-many-relationships-instead

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I got the following error. `SequelizeDatabaseError: Incorrect integer value: 'Falam' for column 'township_id'`

Comment: this is probably association problems.

Comment: I've updated and added `associations` in my question. Please see this.

Comment: try add target key
source.belongsTo(target, {foreignKey: 'fkname', targetKey: 'id'});

Comment: Still not working. `SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: Student.townshipId cannot be null`

Comment: set sourceKey as well..in association for hasMany

Comment: Updated the models in the question. But same error.

Comment: added in the answer

Comment: My friend, thank you so much for helping me that far. I'm now OK with association, i.e. I can now insert `student` together with `parent`. But as you can see, those `townshipId` are hard coded. In the req, township is a text value like `NYC`. (But that `NYC` exists in `townships` table with a `id`.) How can I insert that?

Comment: Updated in my question for my above comment.

Comment: one way i could think  of check township first, find an township with "nyc" name, if there is return you change the value to id.  another way is use upsert on township then insert with return id.  upsert will insert and update on duplicate, which means if nyc exist then it won't do anything . You should use transaction for this case.

Comment: however, i recommend add township route or add it directly to db and use the id , because it easier to manage .

Comment: Thanks. I see clearly your first way to check first if the incoming `NYC` exists in `townships` table and if it is there, grab the `id` and replace it with `NYC`. I think `upset` will not be OK because it will insert if `NYC` is not there in `townships`. It could allow inserting false data. And sorry I don't understand your recommend way in last comment. (There will be routes to CRUD `townships` resource separately.)